# What port is this? Is this mini displayport?

Tags: laptop, video, displayport, mini-displayport

I think this laptop is a Lenovo T540P. Is this port Mini Displayport? The icon above is not the mini displayport icon I normally see.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [Dual Mode [mini] DisplayPort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Dual-mode)

[image]

> Dual-mode DisplayPort (also known as DisplayPort++) allows devices
>   to directly output single-link HDMI and DVI signals using a simple
>   passive adapter that adjusts from the different connector and the
>   lower voltages used by DisplayPort. When a dual-mode transmitter
>   detects that a DVI or HDMI passive adapter is attached, it switches to
>   DVI/HDMI transmission mode which uses the 4-lane main DisplayPort link
>   and the AUX channel link to transmit three TMDS signals, a clock
>   signal and Display Data Channel data/clock. Dual-mode ports are marked
>   with the DP++ logo; most DisplayPort graphics cards, as well as all
>   Thunderbolt ports with mDP connector, support this mode.

Comment: I bought one of these and it seems to work fine. Thanks again. https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00DRK2ZIK

Comment: But it's something about that the max resolution with DP++ is 1920x1200?